# OpenCV 3: several identifiers like "imread" and "FaceRecognizer" are undefined

Tags: opencv, visual-studio-2017, opencv3.1

I've successfully built both latest OpenCV and OpenCV contrib from git on 64-bit Windows 10, using VS 2017. Now the problem is when trying to re-compile a program ([source code](https://pastebin.com/9GnFvvAH)) that previously used OpenCV 2.x The editor displays some errors, like these:

```
images.push_back(imread(path, 0));
>> identifier "imread" is undefined

Ptr<FaceRecognizer> model = createFisherFaceRecognizer();
>> identifier "FaceRecognizer" is undefined
>> identifier "createFisherFaceRecogizer" is undefined

VideoCapture cap(fileName);
>> identifier "VideoCapture" is undefined
```

So far, these are my include files:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2/face.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp"
```

And these are the lines in my Additional Include Directories:

```
C:\opencv\source\contrib\modules\face\include\
C:\opencv\source\core\include\
C:\opencv\source\core\modules\objdetect\include
C:\opencv\source\core\modules\imgproc\include
C:\opencv\source\core\modules\highgui\include\
C:\opencv\source\core\modules\
C:\opencv\source\core\modules\core\include\
%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)
```

**C:\opencv\source\core** contains the whole core of OpenCV, and **C:\opencv\source\contrib** contains the whole OpenCV contrib modules.

I'm not sure whether the issue is some unincluded files, or wrong include settings.

Comment: This has to be a problem with your project's configuration. First, you need to include the right include directory that is under _<path to the build OpenCV>\install\include_. (This might not be the root problem though)

Comment: In my case, the include path means "C:\opencv\build\include", I guess. But there are no *.h/.*.hpp files in it.

Comment: Building the library with VS should have created an _install_ folder (containing include headers, .dll and .lib files) within "_C:\opencv\build_". Did you follow any tutorials?

Comment: Yes. I use this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h-k7aUp8nGY. Hmm maybe I did something wrong. Let me try again.

Comment: The tutorial seems correct and confirms what I said before. In OpenCV VS's project you need to right click on _INSTALL_ configuration and select _build_. That's the step that creates the _install_ folder.